# Kendo angularjs tree view, prevent parent node check by its default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-treeview

Hi am using Kendo treeview with Angularjs, i have tree view with checkbox in below hierarchy

Parent1
  Child1
  Child2

I need like this,

**Scenario 1:**
if user select Parent1-> Child1, Child2 needs to check automatically. This is working fine

**Scenario 2:**
if user select Child1, Child2->Parent1 should not be automatically. **i want to prevent parent checked by default**, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only option available is `checkChildren` that triggers this behavior.

Setting it this to `false`:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  checkboxes: {
    checkChildren: false
  }
});
```

will disable **Scenario 2** in this case you will no longer have available the **scenario 1**.

What you can do is create a small recursive function that goes through all children and `check` them whenever the parent is clicked.